# video cannot play by this code, please tell me answer

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.music);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
            + "rii.mp4");
    controller = new MediaController(this);

    view.setMediaController(controller);
    view.setVideoURI(uri);
    // songobj =MediaPlayer.create(music.this,R.raw.zs);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // songobj.start();
            view.start();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "save",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // songobj.release();
            // songobj.pause();
            view.pause();
        }
    });

}
```

my video in raw folder. please tell me answer i want to play video in video view. when i run the activity it give error that format not supported. i already change format to android mp4 format.

Comment: Please refer http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html and change video format for your device version and try to play

Comment: Please check you os version with supported file format

Comment: formatting is beautiful..isn't it?

Comment: You should really read the [FAQ]

Comment: Please don't include "tell me the answer" in the question. 1. It is rude 2. It is a question, what else would we tell you?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to play audio that's available as a local raw resource (saved in your application's res/raw/ directory):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```

In this case, a "raw" resource is a file that the system does not try to parse in any particular way. However, the content of this resource should not be raw audio. It should be a properly encoded and formatted media file in one of the supported formats.

And here is how you might play from a URI available locally in the system (that you obtained through a Content Resolver, for instance):

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Playing from a remote URL via HTTP streaming looks like this:

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```